# How to ask for the title on cheque?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

If I need to know whose name should I put in title of a cheque, what would be the most precise and educated sentence?

I have to pay someone some money via cheque but I want to ask them whose name should I put in title of the cheque, what should I say which is polite and eloquent ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In British English, one *makes out* a cheque, so you could ask:

> Who should I make the cheque out to, please?

Comment: Should it be "Whom" instead of "Who"?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that *make out* is the most common formulation. A more traditional phrase is to 'write a cheque in favour of somebody'. So the question would be: who should the cheque be written in favour of?

Answer (score 1):

Another tortured but colloquial phrase is "Who do I make it payable to?"

Answer (score 0):

"To whom should I make out the cheque?"

or

"How exactly should I write the payee name?"

or simply and less formally,

"How should I spell your name on this cheque, please?"

are all reasonable alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm the named payee so the check may be issued.